# I need to figure what's happening when I try to center my image by setting my wrapper's text-align to center and my image's display to inline-block

Tags: css

I need to figure what's happening when I try to center my image by setting my wrapper's text-align to center and my image's display. My wrapper for the images are both set to (text-align: center) and my img tags are set to (display: inline-block). Is react getting in the way at all?

```
.heroLogo {
     width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .heroLogo-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: -1;
      @include mediaQ('large'){
          width:40%;
      }
    }
    .heroTitle {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .heroTitle-wrapper{
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
      text-align: center;
      @include mediaQ('large'){
          width:65%;
      }
    }


    //REACT
    //======

    var Logo = () => {
      return(
        <div className='heroLogo-wrapper'>
          <img src={HeroLogoImg} className="heroLogo" />
        </div>
      );
    }
    var Title = () => {
      return(
        <div className='heroTitle-wrapper'>
          <img src={HeroTitleImg} className="heroTitle" />
        </div>

      );
    }
```

Comment: No, react is not getting the way. Try publishing this question with the just the relevant CSS and HTML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. React shouldn't be a problem. It's most likely that your enclosing DIV is not set to `width: 100%`, so having it set in your CSS isn't going to display as wide as you would like it

Comment: Thanks @Mikkel big time!! Thanks for the welcoming too.lol